# Unable to access from local git to bitbucket, config problem

Tags: bitbucket, tls1.2

May be it is new TLS ?

> fatal: unable to access 'https://user@bitbucket.org/team/                          repo.git/': Received HTTP code 404 from proxy after CONNECT

Comment: Can you access that link using a browser?

Comment: A 404 error would indicate a bad URL, not a problem with encryption... is that really a space in the URL there? Do you need to percent-encode it as %20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I used this command.*

```
 git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

and it will done
*$ git push > Counting objects: 17, done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads.

Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done. Writing objects: 100% 

(17/17), 9.83 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 17 (delta 8), reused 0 

(delta 0) remote:*